# Can I use a same form to add and edit form data in angular?

Tags: angular

I have a form to add the data to the database.  I have to create an update feature now,  so I need to know if I can use the same form that I have created to add data to database or make another form for the update feature. What is the best practice?  Should I have to implement update feature as a separate component or that's not necessary?

Answer (score 1):

As long as they are really similar (e.g. they won't have some extra validation rules which will enforce you to write many `if` inside the component) it is good practice to reuse components wherever it is possible.

If you have different endpoints for creating/updating resource you can easily pass custom `onSubmit` function to your form component which will call proper service method.

```
<your-form (onSubmit)="add(...)">
</your-form>

<your-form (onSubmit)="update(...)">
</your-form>
```

Comment: how can i pass two onSubmit, in one html file. i have already used (onSubmit)="add(...)" , now how can i use (onSubmit)="update(...)" in the same form? can you explain me a bit clearly?

Comment: i wanted to ask you that if it is a good practice to use the same form (not using more than once) to create and update. for ex:
<my-form (onSubmit)="update(...)" (onSubmit)="add(...)">
</my-form>